# Could a different wording be given to the email sent when a bounty has not attracted answers or comments?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, email, wording

I received an email saying:

> bounty expiring soon  Mar 28 at 11:03
>
> Your bounty on question "How can I set up networking under Basilisk II / MacOS 8.7?" is completed. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.

[How can I set up networking under Basilisk II / MacOS 8.7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1709142/how-can-i-set-up-networking-under-basilisk-ii-macos-8-7) has a bounty, and unlike some previous questions where a bounty was set, it has not received any response. ([How can I unconfuse my server between cjshayward.com and cshayward.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550140/how-can-i-unconfuse-my-server-between-cjshayward-com-and-cshayward-com) has one answer with my own notes as I went along and found things not working.)

The email response I got for the first question is not a response tailored for a bounty that has not attracted answers or comments. I would suggest that if a bounty has been set, a better default SE behavior should be exhibited for bounties that have no candidate for awards.

**--UPDATE--**

Per Community Manager's [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1259793), here is a screenshot of the email, some info replaced by white rectangles:

[image: screenshot of email]

Comment: It's possible that we can't check whether an answer qualifies but the email seems very brusque and like it could certainly be more clear. "You must award it" is a terrible way to phrase that - far better to offer some explanation "You have a 24-hour grace period to award your bounty to an answer. If the question wasn't answered, no action is needed"... or something.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of the email (please feel free to obscure/redact any personal information if you do)?

Answer (score 4):

In the end, this is something we're not going to fix because the fix could end up being less correct.

I asked Adam about this and the answer I got was an explanation about how the notification system works and how complicated it is -

> That message is generated on the fly when the inbox item is shown rather than when it’s first created. And since the inbox can be viewed from any site, we can’t even rely on being able to query the database (nor would we want to, honestly - the inbox is designed to be viewable with the information it has).
>
> I thought about tracking additional information (such as the number of answers at the time of the grace period start), but that pretty much kicks the same problem can down the road - you could have an inbox notification that says there are no answers even though there were some posted since it was created. Arguably that’s even worse since it’ll potentially lead someone to ignore their bounty if they don’t realize that answers have been posted.
>
> All of that is further compounded by unread email notifications - regardless of what we do on the site, the email might be wildly wrong.

So there doesn't seem to be a way to really address the concern here that would be perfect and simple. That said, we do send out emails daily when a grace period begins and these emails do take into account whether there's been an answer or not. Unfortunately, we send them out only once daily, so it's possible that the email will go out right before the grace period ends.